# TortoiseSvn & Windows7 RC1:  Cannot open .msi, "This installation package could not be opened."

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, tortoise-svn

Has anyone successfully installed it?

When i start .msi to install it, it throws:

> This installation package could not be opened.
>   Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows installer package.

Msi:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/tortoisesvn/TortoiseSVN-1.6.3.16613-win32-svn-1.6.3.msi?download

Comment: Does it work on Windows XP?

Comment: As you determined this error is almost always caused by a corrupted installation file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps try this [mirror from FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_tortoisesvn/tech/), if read more people complaining about the sourceforge download being corrupt

Answer (score 1):

The mailing list said, that TortoiseSVN [should work with Windows 7](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=1014939). To me it seems more like your downloaded package is broken. Did you try to download it again?

Comment: Tried like 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Try changing SourceForge download to different mirror.

Had the same problem for a few last days using my default mirror (NetCologne GmbH; Cologne, Germany, DE), changing to another mirror helped.

Also check instructions of TortoiseSVN developer how to check integrity of downloaded install file: http://tortoisesvn.net/msiverify.html